# Что мешает нормальной работоспособности кода в использовании структур?

Tags: c#, struct

Уже замучился. Вот код:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace oop_lab4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
                       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            int x = 1;
            while (x != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t1. Створити масив абітурієнтів\n\t" +
                    "2. Роздрукувати інформацію про одного абітурієнта\n\t" +
                    "3. Роздрукувати інформацію про всіх абітурієнтів\n\t" +
                    "4. Найвищий та найнищий конкурсний бал\n\t" +
                    "5. Сортування абітурієнтів за конкурсним балом\n\t" +
                    "6. Сортування абітурієнтів за алфавітом\n\t" +
                    "7. Найгірший бал з предмету\n\t" +
                    "8. Найкращий бал з предмету\n\t" +
                    "0. Вихід" +
                    "\n-->");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }

                switch (x)
                {
                    case 1: { ReadEntrantsArray(); break; }
                 /*   case 2: { PrintEntrant(); break; }
                    case 3: { PrintEntrants(); break; }
                    case 4: { GetEntrantsInfo(); break; }
                    case 5: { SortEntrantsByPoints(); break; }
                    case 6: { SortEntrantsByName(); break; }
                    case 7: { GetBestSubject(); break; }
                    case 8: { GetWorstSubject(); break; }*/
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ReadEntrantsArray()
        {
            int n = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("\tКількість абітурієнтів:\n\t-->");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
            }
            Obj[] obj = new Obj[n];



            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"Введіть прізвище та ініціали {i} абітурієнта =");
                obj[i].ent.name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Введіть ідентифікаційний код {i} абітурієнта =");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out obj[i].ent.idNum))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть бали за підготовчі курси =");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out obj[i].ent.coursePoints))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть бал атестату =");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out obj[i].ent.avgPoints))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Кількість предметів ЗНО =");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out obj[i].res[i].kpred))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }


                for (int j = 0; j < obj[i].res[i].kpred; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введіть назву предмета =");
                    obj[i].res[j].subject = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введіть результат =");
                    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out obj[i].res[j].points))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        public struct Entrant
        {
            public string name;
            public int idNum;
            public int coursePoints;
            public int avgPoints;


        }
        public struct ZNO
        {
            public string subject;
            public int points;
            public int kpred;

            public ZNO(string sub, int p, int k)
            {
                subject = sub;
                points = p;
                kpred = k;

            }
            public ZNO(string sub)
            {
                subject = "Dont know";
                points = 3;
                kpred = 1;

            }


        }

        public struct Obj
        {
           public Entrant ent;
            public ZNO[] res;


        }
    }

}
```

Вот ошибка при работе: [image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Я не увидел, чтобы у вас `obj[i].res` где-то инициализировалось

Comment: Они, конечно, структуры, но массив структур - это уже ссылочный тип `... = new ZNO[?];`.

Comment: Поменяйте украиноязычный текст на русскоязычный, для большинства читабельность вопроса сильно ухудшена

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. массив res - это поле структуры, то по умолчанию (если его не инициализировать) он `null`. Вы пытаетесь обратиться по индексу к `null` массиву(`null[i]`, так нельзя), потому и вылетает это исключение.